# What is the meaning and name for "+=" in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, compound-assignment

I am fairly new to C++ and I have been reading and writing some of my own code. I see these operators from time to time, if that is even the right word to use?

```
+= // Not sure what it means
```

So my question is: what do they mean/do, and what are they called?

For further reference, I'd like to know what they are called so I can easily look it up (searching simply for "+=" for instance yielded nothing).

Edit: For anyone else who does not know the meaning (or in my case knew the name of these) I found this Wikipedia link which might come of handy to other people: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: I believe they are called *compound assignment operators*. Should have better luck searching using that term.

Comment: This question could have been easily answered by a Google search, shows very little research effort.

Comment: While you are not incorrect depa, I did not know the name of them so I was searching all kinds of things that were wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but even more so than googling would have done a very (very...) basic C++ tutorial/book. Of course, you don't need to be an expert to ask here, but understanding the very (very...) basics of the language you're delving into might be a good idea. In the end just reading two pages ahead in your favourite C++ book would have been much faster than posting and maintaining a proper SO question. But be it so, didn't downvote it yet, anyway.

Comment: I am following a book, C++ Primer 6th edition - I am into the third chapter and thus far there has been no mentioning of these (as in their names). Mainly it has been cout/cin/data types etc. This is derailing a bit off-topic though and I knew when posting this that it would be a simple answer. Anyhow now that I know the name of them I can do more research. Thanks all for the replies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, these are operators. More specifically, they are known as compound assignment operators. Here's the full list of them:

```
*= /= %= += -= >>= <<= &= ^= |=
```

They are defined like so:

> The behavior of an expression of the form `E1 op = E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1 op E2` except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

So `x += 5;` is almost the same as `x = x + 5;`.

You can think of it as a modifying addition. If you  just do `x + 5`, the result of the expression is what you get if you add `x` and `5` together, but `x` hasn't changed. If you do `x += 5;`, `x` actually has 5 added to its value.

Comment: Say for instance

     int i = 5;
     i += 5; // now i is 10?

Comment: yes it does. basically its just reducing the source code size and increasing readability

Comment: Splendid, thank you. I now know the name of them and can search in the  future :) - Not sure why I got down voted so much, I suppose it is a really simple question (I did not know the name of these). Adding as answer when I am allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

its just an abbreviation:
`a+=2;`  means `a=a+2;`
of course as many operators: you can overload it to give it alternative meaning, ans actually we do it often to provide meaning for example in the case what it means to add int to our class SomeClass:

```
SomeClass s;
s+=1; //operator+=(SomeClass& s, int i){} is used here

class A{
public:
    A():i_(123){}
    ~A(){}
    int i(){return i_;}
    A const& operator+=(int i){
       std::cout<<"operator+=";
       this->i_=i_+i;
    }
private:
    int i_;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    A a1;
    a1+=3;
    std::cout<<a1.i();
    return OK;
}
```

> output: operator+=126

Comment: Well, technically it's a completely different operator (and for a non-builtin type, not only technically but practically).

Comment: of course this is different, but it expands to this, so I explained what it means to use this operator

Comment: It can be overloaded such that its meaning isn't equivalent to the expansion you show.

Comment: of course, but it is not what OP asked for. he asked for basic meaning I think